# Passing arguments to functions, and variable scopes in R

Tags: r, function, scope, default-arguments

I'm writing a simple function that takes two arguments (state, outcome). State is used to subset a dataframe later.

Having said that, part of the requirement is that state be a length 2 character vector. I need to write more code to ensure that the state that is passed conforms to this requirement.

So I wrote the following:

```
best <- function(state, outcome) {

  outcome <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv", colClasses = "character")
  state <- vector(mode = "character", length = 2)
  st.checkTbl <- outcome[8]

  state
  }
```

However, when I call the function and pass the arguments:

```
best("AXA") or best("FOO") or even best("TX") or best(AL)
```

All I get back is: "" ""

If I comment out the #state <- ... then it passes the argument just fine and it prints "FOO" or "AXA" or "TX", etc.

How can I ensure that the argument passed to the function is stored as a variable (state) in the function? Or, am I way overthinking this? Really I just wanted to test that what I am passing to the state argument can be printed for test purposes.

. Sorry for the 101 lesson.

Comment: Sounds like you're over-thinking it. Also, it's not really clear what this function is supposed to do, since all it will return is an empty character vector or, if you comment out the line, the original value you supplied for `state`. You may want to give the "writing your own functions" section of [An Introduction to R manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Writing-your-own-functions).

Comment: No matter what you put in for state, you will override it with `state <- vector(...)` inside the function

Comment: Thomas, I think you're right. I'm overthinking that R just sort of knows what to do with my state argument. I'm trying to figure out how it knows where to send the value of state and proving to myself that it's actually doing what I want it to do.

Comment: @RichardScriven I figured that bit out after thinking about it for a minute, which is why I got back an empty character vector. Thanks!

Comment: You can have a look at your arguments with e.g. `f <- function(x) as.list(match.call()[-1]); f("hello")` and you can see that `x` was entered as "hello"

Comment: You can also debug your function with `debug(best)` and walk through all of the values of objects inside the execution of your function.

Comment: That's excellent. But how do I know exactly where R is storing it and that it knows what to do with it? So if I say best("Texas") and I use some pseudocode [look at state and see if that state is in this table of states] does R implicitly know that when I say "look at state" it's the "state" from my  function argument and not another state? I'm guessing this is because "state" from the function is part of the global environment and since isn't (once I remove the assignment in the function) defined in the function it looks up and finds it? -- time to re-read the scoping !

Comment: Here's some suggested reading: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Fox-Companion/appendix-scope.pdf, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169534/writing-functions-in-r-keeping-scoping-in-mind, http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#lexical-scoping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would generally read your data outside of any function, like so:

```
outcome.data <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv", colClasses = "character")
```

Otherwise, since a function has its own `namespace`, all the variables defined inside of it will vanish upon its return, unless they themselves are returned by the function with `return(...)`. Several objects can be returned by putting them in a list: `return(list(item1=var1, item2=var2))`.

Some functions, such as `assign`, have the `envir` parameter that can be set to `.GlobalEnv` to change this behavior. Altering an object can also be done inside a function using the `<<-` operator instead of `<-`, although this practice is generally recommended against.

As a side note, when using a function, you need to define clearly:

1. What are its inputs
2. What does it do
3. What does it return

It's not useful, for instance, to use `outcome` as a function parameter and then read into a variable named `income` the content of a csv file. Your argument is then useless as it will be written over. That's why you had to comment out the line defining your `state` variable inside the function to actually be able to use `state` as it was received by the function.

This surely won't answer all your questions, but hopefully it can help you clarify certain things. For the rest there are plenty of good tutorials to learn further on how to program in R and how/when to use functions. Best of luck and happy learning!

Comment: While helpful, I don't think this advice answer's the OP's main question, which is about variable scope.

Comment: You're right. I added a little bit of explanation for that matter. Hopefully the OP finds it useful even if not entirely satisfactory as an answer.

Comment: Excellent help though @DominicComtois and I do appreciate it. I really like R and am learning to love all of this data science stuff! So would you recommend a function that reads all of my data and then passing those variables into the function that crunches them?

Comment: @Zach For reading the data, generally it's done outside a function. If you have many files to read, you can for instance write a loop that would put all dataframes (created by read.csv or read.table) in a list. Then yes, using a function or several functions could be a good idea to do some crunching. But the main work can be in the GlobalEnv (outside any function) and then you might need to write several little functions that do specific things. Deciding when it's worth it to write a function or not comes with practice. They're generally a way to avoid repetition, but they're not the ONLY way!