# Making a Variable Constant in a Function in R

Tags: r, function

Is there any way I can define a function in R with a constant determined from a variable? I'm not sure how to say that better so here is an example.

```
> index<-3
> f<-function(x){x+index}
> f(4)
[1] 7     #Great!
> index<-20
> f(4)
[1] 24   #No! I still want to see 7!
```

Thank you!

Comment: Advanced R's chapter on environments seems relevant: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html

Comment: Might want to see http://stackoverflow.com/q/1169534

Comment: So I ultimately went with BenBarnes' approach for the short term but will keep reading up on environments as suggested by paljenczy to hopefully come up with something a little "nicer".  Thank you both!

Comment: Two search terms that would likely have led you to a solution are "partial function" and "Currying".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is to define your function within another function:

```
g <- function( index ){
  function( x ) x + index
}
index <- 3
f <- g( index )
f(4)
index<-20
f(4)
```

Now the output of `g( index )` is a function which is defined within the (execution) environment of `g`. This function (`f`) will look at the value of `index`in this environment, where it is fixed to 3. That's why it works, but maybe there is a simpler solution.

Comment: Thank you! This looks like what BenBarnes was suggesting in a comment above but I didn't quite "get it" until I read your solution.

Answer (score 2):

Look for `?lockBinding`, your answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936748/declaring-a-const-variable-in-r)

```
index <- 3
lockBinding("index", globalenv())
index <- 4
#> Error: cannot change value of locked binding for 'index'
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'd like to be able to be able to change the value of "index" after the function is defined. Ideally, if I looked at the function, I would see this: function(x){x+3}.